# extending \hline across the full width of nested tabular

Tags: tables, hline, hfill

**So I'm trying to figure out how to extend the horizontal line in the last column across the full width. I'm using nested tabular but can't seem to use \hfil or anything similar to get it to work. Is there anyway to get it look better, or is it not possible with this method?**

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|@{}c@{}|}
\hline

\textbf{Author} & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Measurements} &  \textbf{Data $\pm$ SD (kPa) / Conclusions} \\ 
\hline

\shortstack{Holzapfel\\2004} & Iliac & 
\shortstack{Ultimate tensile \\ stress \& stretch of \\ Fibrous Cap } & 
\begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}} Circumferential & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\bar{\sigma}_{ult}$ & $254.8\pm 79.8$\\ \hline $\bar{\lambda}_{ult}$ & $1.18\pm 0.1$ \\ \end{tabular} \\ \hline Axial & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\bar{\sigma}_{ult}$ & $468.6\pm 100.1$\\ \hline $\bar{\lambda}_{ult}$ & $1.135\pm0.071$\\ \end{tabular} \\ \end{tabular} \\
\hline

\shortstack{Maher\\2009} & Carotid & 
\shortstack{C\\values} & 
\begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}} Calcified & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $c_{10}$ & $1.144\pm10.6$\\ \hline $c_{20}$ & $1.392\pm31.33$ \\ \end{tabular} \\ \hline Mixed Plaque & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $c_{10}$ & $7.53\pm16.16$\\ \hline $c_{20}$ & $20.63\pm49.85$\\ \end{tabular} \\ \end{tabular} \\
\hline

\shortstack{Lawlor\\2011} & Carotid & 
\shortstack{Fracture stress \& stretch \\ (direction?)} & 

\begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}} 
Hard & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $c_{10}$ & $302.1$\\ \hline $c_{20}$ & $-228$ \\ \end{tabular} \\ \hline 
Mixed & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $c_{10}$ & $23.5$\\ \hline $c_{20}$ & $126$\\ \end{tabular}  \\ \hline
Tensile Fracture & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\bar{\sigma}_{ult}$ & $366.6 \pm 220.5$\\ \hline $\bar{\epsilon}_{ult}$ & $0.49 \pm 0.088$ \\ \end{tabular} \\ 
\end{tabular} \\ 
\hline

\shortstack{Teng\\2014} & Carotid & 
\shortstack{Elastic Moduli \\ vs. stretch} & 
\begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}} compression & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\bar{\sigma}_{ult}$ & value\\ \hline c20 & value \\ \end{tabular} \\ \hline tension & \begin{tabular}{c|c} c10 & value\\ \hline c20 & value\\ \end{tabular} \\ \end{tabular} \\
\hline

\shortstack{Jankowska\\2015} & Coronary & 
\shortstack{Tensile Fracture Stretch \\ Longitudinal Direction} & 
\shortstack{see graph of \\ disease progression} \\
\hline

\shortstack{Davis\\2016} & Carotid & 
\shortstack{Fracture \\ of FC} & 
\shortstack{larger fracture seen with\\ a lower collagen \%} \\
\hline

\shortstack{Leng\\2018} & Carotid & 
\shortstack{Visco-elastic \\ Anisotropic Model} & 
\begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}} Fibrous Cap & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\bar{\mu}$ & $0.82\pm0.3$\\ \hline $\bar{k}_1$ & $1952.62\pm1735.29$ \\ \end{tabular} \\ \hline Diseased Media & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\bar{\mu}$ & $0.27\pm0.45$\\ \hline $\bar{k}_1$ & $3194\pm1812.20$\\ \end{tabular} \\ \end{tabular} \\
\hline

\shortstack{Kobielarz\\2020} & \shortstack{Abdominal \\ Aorta} & 
\shortstack{Elastic Moduli \\ axial (circ not incl.)} & 
\begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}} 
Fibrotic \hfil & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\sigma_m$ & $6566$\\ \hline $E$ & $1640$ \\ \end{tabular} \\ \hline 
Lipid \hfil & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\sigma_m$ & $510$\\ \hline $E$ & $126$\\ \end{tabular}  \\ \hline
Calcified \hfil & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\sigma_m$ & NF?\\ \hline $E$ & $6670$ \\ \end{tabular} \\ 
\end{tabular} \\
\hline

\shortstack{Paritala\\2020} & Carotid & 
\shortstack{Fracture \\ cauchy} & 
\begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}} Uncalcified & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\bar{\lambda}$ & $1.57\pm0.15$\\ \hline $\bar{\sigma}_{Cauchy}$ & $322.48\pm528.98$ \\ \end{tabular} \\ \hline Calcification & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\bar{\lambda}$ & $1.79\pm1.5$\\ \hline $\bar{\sigma}_{Cauchy}$ & $888.75\pm1724.13$\\ \end{tabular} \\ \end{tabular} \\
\hline

%\shortstack{Sanders\\2020} & Carotid & 
%\shortstack{stiffness \\ c1} & 
%\begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}} compression & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\bar{\sigma}_{ult}$ & value\\ \hline c20 & value \\ \end{tabular} \\ \hline tension & \begin{tabular}{c|c} c10 & value\\ \hline c20 & value\\ \end{tabular} \\ \end{tabular} \\
%\hline

\shortstack{Lisický\\2021} & Carotid & 
\shortstack{fracture stress \& strain \\ of fibrous caps from \\ males \& females} & 
\begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}} Female & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\bar{\sigma}_{\text{calcified}}$ & value\\ \hline $\bar{\sigma}_{\text{uncalcified}}$ & value \\ \end{tabular} \\ \hline Male & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\bar{\sigma}_{\text{calcified}}$ & value\\ \hline $\bar{\sigma}_{\text{uncalcified}}$ & value\\ \end{tabular} \\ \end{tabular} \\
\hline

\caption{uniaxial results. stretches are dimensionless. it is the stresses which take kPa.}
\end{longtable}\label{tab:uniaxialresults}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table looks very choppy to me because of the different column widths of the inner tables. Therefore, I suggest to use one table with six columns.

Also, I would reduce the number of lines to some few horizontal lines
for a more professional looking table (IMHO), see the documentation of package `booktabs`.

[image: \InnerRowSep as \cmidrule]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand*{\RowSep}{\midrule}
\newcommand*{\InnerRowSep}{\cmidrule(lr){4-6}}
%\newcommand*{\InnerRowSep}{\addlinespace}

\newcommand*{\tshortstack}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand*{\TS}[1]{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{\tshortstack{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{cccl@{}c@{}c}
\caption{uniaxial results. stretches are dimensionless. it is the stresses which take kPa.}
\label{tab:uniaxialresults}\\
\toprule

\textbf{Author} &
\textbf{Location} &
\textbf{Measurements} &
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Data $\pm$ SD (kPa) / Conclusions}} \\
\midrule

\TS{Holzapfel\\ 2004} &
  Iliac &
  \TS{Ultimate tensile stress\\ \& stretch of Fibrous\\ Cap} &
  Circumferential & $\bar{\sigma}_{ult}$ & $254.8\pm 79.8$\\*
  &&&             & $\bar{\lambda}_{ult}$ & $1.18\pm 0.1$ \\*
  \InnerRowSep
  &&& Axial & $\bar{\sigma}_{ult}$ & $468.6\pm 100.1$\\*
  &&&       & $\bar{\lambda}_{ult}$ & $1.135\pm0.071$\\
\RowSep

\TS{Maher\\ 2009} &
  Carotid &
  C values &
  Calcified & $c_{10}$ & $1.144\pm10.6$\\*
  &&&         & $c_{20}$ & $1.392\pm31.33$ \\*
  \InnerRowSep
  &&& Mixed Plaque & $c_{10}$ & $7.53\pm16.16$\\*
  &&&             & $c_{20}$ & $20.63\pm49.85$\\
\RowSep

\TS{Lawlor\\ 2011} &
  Carotid &
  \TS{Fracture stress \&\\ stretch (direction?)} &
  Hard & $c_{10}$ & $302.1$\\*
  &&&  & $c_{20}$ & $-228$ \\*
  \InnerRowSep
  &&& Mixed & $c_{10}$ & $23.5$\\*
  &&&       & $c_{20}$ & $126$\\*
  \InnerRowSep
  &&& Tensile Fracture & $\bar{\sigma}_{ult}$ & $366.6 \pm 220.5$\\*
  &&&                  & $\bar{\epsilon}_{ult}$ & $0.49 \pm 0.088$ \\
\RowSep

Teng 2014 &
  Carotid &
  \TS{Elastic Moduli vs.\\ stretch} &
  compression & $\bar{\sigma}_{ult}$ & value\\*
  &&&         & c20 & value \\*
  \InnerRowSep
  &&& tension & c10 & value\\*
  &&&         & c20 & value\\
\RowSep

\tshortstack{Jankowska\\ 2015} &
  Coronary &
  \tshortstack{Tensile Fracture Stretch\\ Longitudinal Direction} &
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{see graph of disease progression} \\
\RowSep

Davis 2016 &
  Carotid &
  Fracture of FC &
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{larger fracture seen with a lower collagen \%} \\
\RowSep

Leng 2018 &
  Carotid &
  \TS{Visco-elastic\\ Anisotropic Model} &
  Fibrous Cap & $\bar{\mu}$ & $0.82\pm0.3$\\*
  &&&         & $\bar{k}_1$ & $1952.62\pm1735.29$ \\*
  \InnerRowSep
  &&& Diseased Media & $\bar{\mu}$ & $0.27\pm0.45$\\*
  &&&                & $\bar{k}_1$ & $3194\pm1812.20$\\
\RowSep

\TS{Kobielarz\\ 2020} &
  \TS{Abdominal\\ Aorta} &
  \TS{Elastic Moduli\\ axial (circ not incl.)} &
  Fibrotic & $\sigma_m$ & $6566$\\*
  &&&        & $E$ & $1640$ \\*
  \InnerRowSep
  &&& Lipid & $\sigma_m$ & $510$\\*
  &&&       & $E$ & $126$\\*
  \InnerRowSep
  &&& Calcified  & $\sigma_m$ & NF?\\*
  &&&            & $E$ & $6670$ \\
\RowSep

\TS{Paritala\\ 2020} &
  Carotid &
  Fracture cauchy &
  Uncalcified & $\bar{\lambda}$ & $1.57\pm0.15$\\*
  &&&         & $\bar{\sigma}_{Cauchy}$ & $322.48\pm528.98$ \\*
  \InnerRowSep
  &&& Calcification & $\bar{\lambda}$ & $1.79\pm1.5$\\*
  &&&               & $\bar{\sigma}_{Cauchy}$ & $888.75\pm1724.13$\\
\RowSep

%\shortstack{Sanders\\2020} & Carotid &
%\shortstack{stiffness \\ c1} &
%\begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}} compression & \begin{tabular}{c|c} $\bar{\sigma}_{ult}$ & value\\ \hline c20 & value \\ \end{tabular} \\ \hline tension & \begin{tabular}{c|c} c10 & value\\ \hline c20 & value\\ \end{tabular} \\ \end{tabular} \\
%\hline

\TS{Lisický\\ 2021} &
  Carotid &
  \TS{fracture stress \& strain\\ of fibrous caps from\\ males \& females} &
  Female & $\bar{\sigma}_{\text{calcified}}$ & value\\*
  &&&    & $\bar{\sigma}_{\text{uncalcified}}$ & value \\*
  \InnerRowSep
  &&& Male & $\bar{\sigma}_{\text{calcified}}$ & value\\*
  &&&      & $\bar{\sigma}_{\text{uncalcified}}$ & value\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

### Remarks

- The base line of a `\shortstack` is the base line of the bottom row. However, the reading order is top to bottom. To get an alignment at the top row, I defined a `\tshortstack` via a `tabular` environment with the optional argument `[t]`.
- With the new table design, the multi-line entries of the first three columns would all consume vertical space of the whole table row. Therefore, I defined `\TS` to use `\tshortstack` but with setting the depth to zero. Thus, TeX thinks, there is just one line (similar to package `multirow`). The disadvantage is that the user must ensure, that there is enough space for the multi-line cell below its top row.
- I have left-aligned the fourth column to make the table layout more clear.
- The table data in the last columns allow to remove the space between columns (`{...l@{}c@{}c}`).
- Macro `\RowSep` and `\InnerRowSep` are just a convenience macro for experimenting (`\midrule` vs. `\addlinespace`). IMHO, `\RowSep` as `\midrule` makes the main rows more clear. `\InnerRowSep` as `\cmidrule` is shown above and as `\addlinespace` is shown below. The latter might look a little more pleasant.

[image: \InnerRowSep as \addlinespace]

Comment: ahh amazing! thank you so much :) :)